# Are limits categorical limits?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Category-theoretic limit related to topological limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/category-theoretic-limit-related-to-topological-limit)

I was wondering if there exists some way to re-interpret "analytical" limits
$$ \lim_{x\to c}\; f(x)$$
as *categorical* limits/colimits of a functor $F\colon J\to \bf C$.

This could be done following a naive point of view, the analogy
$$\text{cnts function}\iff \text{cnts functor}$$ 
but I feel there are some evident problems: for a function of top spaces $f\colon X\to Y$, just assume $Y$ to be non-Hausdorff and uniqueness of limit $\lim_{x\to c}$ is lost. Is there some way to link these kind of limits to weak limits in Category Theory?

In fact a deeply linked question is: how to categorify the notion of limit of a sequence on a topological space? This turns out to be easier; just consider $\mathbb N$ as a discrete category, a sequence $f\colon \mathbb N\to X$ is then a functor from $\mathbb N$ to... well, the bare problem I can't get what is the right way to categorify a topological space: discrete category? Or maybe I should exploit in some way the definition of a *Grothendieck* topology.

To tell the truth, I hardly believe that nobody studied this kind of problem: maybe I'm not able to find good references.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [these](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6554/terminology-in-category-theory) [two](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9951/limits-in-category-theory-and-analysis) MO questions.

Comment: I think [this thread here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60590/5363) is better than the linked ones.