# Relation between inverse limits (and direct limits) with limits in calculus.

Tags: calculus, commutative-algebra

What is the relation between [inverse limit](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseLimit.html) (and [direct limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit)) with limits in calculus? Are there some special cases that an inverse limit (or direct limit) is a limit in calculus (for example, the limit of a sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots$). Thank you very much.

Comment: My intuition is to say that limits in calculus gave limits in category theory their name. (If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a poset, then a diagram of shape $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing sequence $a_0, a_1, \dots$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and a direct limit of the diagram is a limit in the classical sense. This probably isn't deep, though; can we (easily) talk about $\mathbb{C}$, or other topologies, or non-monotone sequences? Still, somehow they both talk about increasingly accurate approximations.) Look up the *p-adic integers* (and their topology), though.

Comment: A very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/category-theoretic-limit-related-to-topological-limit