# Intuition for the definition of a dense functor?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

A functor $i:S\to C$ is *dense* if every object $c$ of $C$ is the vertex of the colimit of the following diagram $\varinjlim((i/c)\stackrel{\mathrm{pr}_S}{\longrightarrow} S \stackrel{i}{\to} C)$.

I would like to understand how this definition captures the intuitive case of limits in topological spaces. I thought of using the "categorical" characterization of convergence via filters, which is just $F\rightarrow x\iff N_x\subset F$ where $F$ is a filter on $X$ and $N_x$ is the neighborhood filter of $x$. Unfortunately, I'm having a lot of difficulty filling in the blanks. What would the colimit above look like in these case? I think the functor $i$ would be the functor $E$ from [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60590/category-theoretic-limit-related-to-topological-limit), but I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: I'm not sure there is actually a connection of the type you are looking for.

Comment: @ZhenLin expressing points in a space as limits of nets in dense subspaces seems to be inherently arbitrary, so maybe what I want is unreasonable to expect.. Could you perhaps help me get a feel for what exactly the colimit $\varinjlim((i/c)\stackrel{\mathrm{pr}_S}{\longrightarrow} S \stackrel{i}{\to} C)$ encodes "geometrically"? I tried reading what [Lawvere](http://at.yorku.ca/t/o/p/d/65.htm) says, but it was too terse for me.